# commenting out @profile decorators when line-profiling

Tags: python, profiling

Popular solution for Python line profiling seems to be `kernprof -l script.py`, which requires adding "@profile" decorators to functions you want to profile. Running the same code without as `python script.py` will complain "name 'profile' not defined" so you have to comment out `@profile` lines. What's a good work-around to switch between "profile" and non-profile modes without having to comment out those lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to add something like this at the top of your script:

```
try:
    profile  # throws an exception when profile isn't defined
except NameError:
    profile = lambda x: x   # if it's not defined simply ignore the decorator.
```

That way you define the `profile` function as no-op decorator if it's not defined.

Comment: But if you try to run the kernprof like `kernprof -l  --setup script.py script.py`, this overrides the profiler even on the second run.